# What explains T5's recent resurgence?

Tags: nlp, language-model, social-network-analysis

I read on https://towardsdatascience.com/choosing-the-right-language-model-for-your-nlp-use-case-1288ef3c4929:

[image]

I find the curve for T5 to be particularly interesting. What explains its recent resurgence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see FLAN-T5 in the list as well as the other T5 variants, so my guess is that all T5 variants got conflated into T5. Since fine-tuning (eg, FLAN-T5) has become very important in language models, this likely explains T5's recent resurgence according to the plot in the question details.